# What should I install to query SQL Server DB from Powershell - could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

On my computer I have only SQL Server Management Studio installed.
I use `runas.exe /netonly /user:myDomain\myUser powershell.exe` to open Powershell console (I need to authenticate to SQL Server using Windows Authentication).
Then I connect to SQL Server DB using following code:

```
$myConnectionString = "Server=$($serverName);Database=$($dbName);Trusted_Connection=True;"

$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString = $myConnectionString
$SQLConnection.Open()

$SQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT top 2 * FROM [myTable]" 
$SQLCommand.Connection = $SQLConnection
```

Unfortunately when I type:
`$SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()`

I receive an error:

> An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, V ersion=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find t he file specified.. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + $SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator:DbEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

After searching the Internet, I thought that I should install 'SQLSysClrTypes' (from SQL Server Feature Pack).

Thus I downloaded it, but it seems that I have this component installed on my local computer (installer allows me to repair or remove this component only).

What should I install to be able to query the DB from Powershell? On which computer should I install that computer?

---

**EDIT:**

When I log into the server through RDP (mstsc), and use following connection string:

`$myConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=$($dbName);Trusted_Connection=True;"`

I do not experience such issues - `ExecuteReader()` returns results.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any additional tools or libraries to query MS SQL Server from PowerShell, assuming you are running Windows 7 or newer.

The installed .NET framework has all ADO.NET components required to do this.

If you get an error, something is wrong with your script or your environment.

Comment: I'm under Windows 10 and the server with SQL Server is Windows Server 2012 R2. Maybe it's because I use `runas.exe /netonly`? Or I provided `$serverName =  'IP.add.r.ess,port' ` in incorrect format (but if it's in incorrect format, why I was able to `open()` connection?

Comment: do you have any idea / suggestion what to do / how to investigate what is the source of issue?

Comment: Always start with the most basic setup, using a normal local PowerShell session, not sure about the `netonly` but try without it. I am not sure why that error would come up. Can you run the same script on the server itself?

Comment: I verified that when I run the same script on the server, I am able to obtain results (I added this information in Edit part). It works on the server in both cases - using a normal local PowerShell session and when I run Powershell using `runas` command.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that there must be a better solution, thus I will not mark this response as an answer...

I checked the content of `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` path and discovered that I have `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` for versions 12, 13 and 14.
Thus I just copy-paste mentioned file for version `10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91` from the server to my computer...and it works
So, it seems that somewhere it's hardcoded to use this specific version of Assembly when connecting to SQL Server from Powershell (?)